# Where can I find documentation on biblatex 1.7 (or other older versions of packages)?

Tags: biblatex, documentation, obsolete

I have just updated my `MikTeX 2.9` (I'm using `Windows 7`)... and surprise! My citations don't work any more and I get cryptic error messages. Panic! After a few minutes of frantic and more or less random trial and (inevitably) error attempts, I decided to read the manual. (Yep, should have started with that one!)

So I learn that `biblatex 2.0` uses `biber` as back-end and I need to specify explicitly that I want to force it to use the old `bibtex` back-end. Works fine, thanks! Still, the documentation also says that if the back-end is `bibtex`, `biblatex` will revert to version 1.7. So my question is: **where do I find the documentation for `biblatex 1.7`?** (Googling didn't help...) **Or for that matter documetation for older versions of LaTeX packages?**

**P.S.** Don't tell me to switch to `biber`! I intend to do that... in due time. For now I have a large document that still needs some serious editing and absolutely no urge to experiment... Thanks for your understanding! `:)`

Comment: [Is this it?](http://www.math.upenn.edu/tex_docs/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf)

Comment: @ScottH.: THANKS! `:)` how about making it an answer?

Comment: Just refer to the 2.0 documentation and ignore any content marked "biber only". The "revert" business just has to do with the fact that most development since 1.7 was made possible by biber. So with BibTeX, 2.0 is essentially the same as 1.7 (barring some bug fixes).

Comment: @Mico: I do that, I use that option and all's fine, as I said in my post. I just want to have the documentation for the old version. It might be handy to spot differences compared to newer versions. Thanks anyway! `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the documentation for Biblatex 1.7.

http://www.math.upenn.edu/tex_docs/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf

I have no idea, in general, about where such things can be found.  When I look for something like this, I find that it helps to restrict my google search to pdf and search for `filetype:pdf biblatex 1.7`

Answer (score 9):

As Audrey has commented, the v2.0 documentation is still 'correct' for the BibTeX back end. Almost everything new in v2.0 compared with v1.7 is Biber-only, and is marked as such. In that sense, `biblatex` is broadly frozen for BibTeX users (bugs in that part will be fixed, but the open requests for features all really need Biber). So you should be fine with the current documentation, just keep an eye on the 'Biber-only' statements.

---

Obviously this is specific to `biblatex`. For a more general way to find 'old' documentation, you could look at Martin Scharrer's CTAN-Hg mirror of CTAN, or the [TeX Live SVN system](http://tug.org/texlive/svn/) (provided what you want is in TL, of course).

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth! `:)`